# test swift async function timeout

Tags: swift, async-await, xctestexpectation

How do you write a unit test that checks whether an async function doesn't timeout?

I'm trying with regular `XCTestExpectation`, but because `await` suspends everything, it can't wait for the expectation.

In the code below, I'm checking that `loader.perform()` doesn't take more than 1 second to execute.

```swift
func testLoaderSuccess() async throws {    
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "doesn't timeout")

    let result = try await loader.perform()

    XCTAssert(result.value == 42)

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1) // execution never gets here

    expectation.fulfill()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be prudent to cancel the task if it times out:

```swift
func testA() async throws {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "timeout")

    let task = Task {
        let result = try await loader.perform()
        XCTAssertEqual(result, 42)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    await fulfillment(of: [expectation], timeout: 1)
    task.cancel()
}
```

If you do not, `perform` may continue to run even after `testA` finishes in the failure scenario.

---

The other approach would be to use a task group:

```swift
func testB() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask {
            let result = try await self.loader.perform()
            XCTAssertEqual(result, 42)
        }
        group.addTask {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            XCTFail("Timed out")
        }
        let _ = try await group.next() // wait for the first one
        group.cancelAll()              // cancel the other one
    }
}
```

Comment: New Swift API requires using `await fulfillment(of: [expectation], timeout: 1)` inside async context

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks! Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure this in a different way.

You need to create a new `Task`. In this `Task` execute and await the async code. After awaiting fulfill the expectation.

Your code did not work because the Thread the Test runs on will stop at `wait(for:` for the expectation to fulfill, what it never does as the line comes after `wait(for:`.

```
func testLoaderSuccess() throws {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "doesn't timeout")

    Task{
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 500_000_000)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)

    // Assertions here because only then is assured that  
    // everything completed
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the assertions after the `wait` weren't getting hit for me..

Comment: @Eric this is a more general example to show how to structure this to be able to fulfill the expectation. I did the Assertions after wait if there are multiple task to fulfill and you need to wait for more than one.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence that worked for me both locally and on CI is the following:

```swift
func testLoaderSuccess() async throws {    
    Task {
        let result = try await loader.perform()
        XCTAssert(result.value == 42)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following function based on [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73720694/2229783):

```
func testAwait(timeout: UInt64, task: @escaping () async -> Void) async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask {
            await task()
        }
        group.addTask {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC)
            XCTFail("Timed out")
        }
        let _ = try await group.next()
        group.cancelAll()
    }
}
```

This is how you can use it:

```
try await testAwait(timeout: 1) {
    let result = try await loader.perform()
    XCTAssert(result.value == 42)
}
```

Comment: I might suggest swapping the order of the parameters. By convention (and to enjoy “trailing closure” syntax), the closure is usually the last parameter.